# Find alphabetical letter from a (smiles) string not from a list of elements

Tags: sql, bioinformatics, hue

**OBJECTIVE**

Filter out the SMILES strings if any alphabetical letter (atoms) in the string, **insensitive to capitalization**, does not come from the following list of elements `H, B, C, N, O, F, Al, Si, P, S, Cl`, this is a truncated list. In total, there are 38 elements.

**BACKGROUND**

I have a database containing SMILES strings:

> The simplified molecular-input line-entry system (SMILES) is a specification in the form of a line notation for describing the structure of chemical species using short ASCII strings.

(More info [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system))

SMILES example:

```
OC[C@H]1O[C@H]([C@H](O)[C@@H]1O)n1cnc2c(NC3CCCC3)ncnc12
```

The purpose of this was to get rid of rare elements and organometallics from the database.

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Hi Tim, I am using Hue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One general approach would work on any version of SQL would be to create a table which contains a blacklist of not allowed atomic symbols.  Smiles to be retained would be those which do not match to any blacklisted element symbol.

```
WITH disallowed AS (
    SELECT 'He' AS symbol UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Li' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Be' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Ne' UNION ALL
    ...
    SELECT 'Lr'
)

SELECT t1.smile
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM disallowed t2
                  WHERE t1.smile LIKE '%' || t2.symbol || '%');
```

A compound such as UO<sub>2</sub> would be filtered off by the above inner join, it having the blacklisted element uranium in it.

Comment: There are  118 elements in the periodic table. So there will be 80 not allowed atomic symbols, which is a long list to type. Is there a way to type something like ```not in ['a', 'bb', 'Bc']```?

Comment: @June ... and your whitelist of 38 elements is also rather long.  Either way, you need some kind of calendar table approach here.

Comment: I see. If listing all the elements at once would not work, I would use other programming languages to handle the issue. Thank you for your time!